# My computer shuts down whenever I launch the emulator on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've started using Android Studio recently, and I've already launched the emulator, which until now worked fine: It opened quickly and displayed my app. But a few days ago, instead of opening quickly, it got stuck on the loading screen for quite some time, before the computer shut itself.

I've searched for solutions on the internet, and one of them was enabling/disabling Instant Run. So this time I disabled it before launching the emulator, but again, the emulator got stuck on the loading screen before the computer shut itself. After that I enabled Instant Run again, but the computer shut itself in the third time. And today, the same old story.

The emulator I'm trying to launch is Nexus 5 API 29.

Thanks

Comment: without being able to give us an example we could recreate, there's no way anyone could really answer this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same problem. It has to do with the computer memory, that means your AVD or emulator is too big for your computer. Your computer cannot handle your emulator/AVD.  Best solution is to connect a real Android device to your computer and run your application. That worked for me.

Comment: But if my computer can't handle the emulator, how come the emulator has already worked for me in the past?

Comment: That is a good question, your emulator worked in the past because your computer had a lot of memory then. Remember every time you use your computer and create projects, its memory is being reduced. That means it does not have much memory now then then.

Comment: Solved. I simply reinstalled the emulator. Thanks

Comment: I am having same issue. Not sure how to fix that. I have increased the memory setting to 4 gb of ram but still facing same issue. let me try reinstalling the emulator again.

Comment: I don’t understand. With android studio and emulator on, I have less than 40% of memory used. But still powers down the pc

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue

Comment: For me, wiping the data of the emulator fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to install the emulator Accelerator in Android Studio. It increase the emulator accelarator.

[image]